# Writing and checking your own concepts in c++

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

I am writing a header-only C++ library that uses templates quite a lot. Now I want to add some concepts checking to handle compile-time errors raised when incorrect types are used in template parameters.

For example, I need concept for pointer-like objects that could point to a single object (like std::shared_ptr), pointer-like object that could point to an array (via operator[]) but couldn't be used with pointer arithmetic (like std::unique_ptr), and pointers that could be used  with pointer arithmetic and so on.

Since concepts are still not in standard and not supported by the compilers, I need to implement this by myself. I know about Boost Concept library, but for some reason I do not want to add it to dependencies.

So the question is, how to implement checking of some type requirements? How is it implemented in Boost? What techniques are common in such cases?

Comment: Good news. The GCC concepts branch merged into trunk.

Comment: There are typically one or two basic principles for concept emulation, but there's a great variation in how the concept checks are implemented based on those principles. Asking for *common techniques* or *how it is implemented* is probably too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Why not describe one of these principles or both of them in answer with their advantages/disatvantages and code examples ?

Answer (score 4):

I've done a little bit of this sort of thing myself since I've still been using C++11. Essentially, the way to do it is heavy use of SFINAE and a good familiarity with all of these things: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types

The most important of those for concept checking is arguably `enable_if`: it's a template that provides a given return type if the first template parameter is `true` and results in a substitution failure if that parameter is `false`:

```
//this one gets called only for pointers
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type do_stuff(T) {}

//this one gets called only for non-pointers
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<not is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type do_stuff(T) {}
```

If you don't care about being able to overload things like that and you like readable error messages, you should use `static_assert` instead:

```
template <typename T>
class pointer_thingy {
    static_assert(is_pointer<T>::value, "T must be a pointer");
    //...
};
```

Now, on to the more difficult part of this: defining your own concept-like template things. If possible, the best way to do this is to just write them in terms of the already existing standard ones from the link above. However, sometimes you want to check things that aren't available there, like, say, the availability of a particular operation. In this case SFINAE is your friend:

```
template <typename T>
class is_equality_comparable {
    template <typename U> static auto check(const U& u) -> typename std::conditional<
            std::is_convertible<decltype(u == u), bool>::value,
            std::true_type, std::false_type>::type;
    static std::false_type check(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

This checks if a particular type has the equality operator (`operator==`) defined and if it returns something that can be used as a `bool`. How it does this warrants some explanation, though: the main thing that this class does is to define a `check` method that is never called and to generate the correct value by computing `check`'s return type. At the bottom, the class does just that: it determines the return type of `check` when called with an imaginary value of type `T` (generated via `declval` in order to avoid dependence on constructors). In order for this to work correctly, two overloads of `check` are provided: the first is templated and the second uses the `...` notation in order to accept any arguments and to have a lower selection priority than the first overload. The first overload uses a suffix return type so that it can refer to its parameter (which makes the code *a lot* cleaner) and uses `conditional` to choose between `true_type` and `false_type` based on whether `operator==` correctly returns something that can be used as a `bool`. If `operator==` doesn't exist, the first overload results in a substitution failure and SFINAE ensures that it is quietly discarded from the list of possible overloads, meaning that the hypothetical call to `check` falls back to the second overload which simply returns `false_type`.

Of course, this is just my way of doing this; it's a method that works, but I'm not sure if this is how Boost does it or, for that matter, if it is how anyone else does it. If you're able to use a newer version of C++ with real concepts support, you should definitely use that instead: among other nice features, you'll be able to get comprehensible error messages if you do something wrong, which is not necessarily something you'll get out of the methods mentioned above. As a final note, if you actually decide to do something like this, rigorous testing is crucial: it's really easy to get something wrong and really hard to figure out how to fix it when your class is already used elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `std::conditional<.., true_type, false_type>` can be shortened to `std::integral_constant<bool, ..>`. More generally, I think it should be noted that the way to define new concepts you've shown is nowadays probably considered quite long-winded (and close to C++03 legacy). It's certainly good enough to demonstrate the techniques, but far from, say, boost.hana's `auto has_name = is_valid([](auto&& x) -> decltype((void)x.name) { });` example, or just Walter E. Brown's `void_t` technique.